# The entity or complex type 'WebServices.UserProfile' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm not looking for any one to resolve the issue mentioned in the title I'm asking for advice purely because I have fixed it my self but I want to get some experts advice, I have a method which loads the user details and returns UserProfile() class

As shown below, key point when running the application with the below code I get the above error.

```
public UserProfile LoadUserDetails(Int64 userId)
    {
        var userProfile = new UserProfile();

        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            userProfile = (from p in context.UserProfile
                           where p.UserId == userId
                           select new UserProfile()
                           {
                               UserId = userId,
                               Firstname = p.Firstname,
                               Surname = p.Surname,
                               Username = p.Username,
                               CurrentlyOnline = p.CurrentlyOnline,
                               JoinedDate = p.JoinedDate,
                               UserLocation = p.UserLocation
                           }).FirstOrDefault();

            context.Dispose();
        }
        return userProfile;
    }
```

If I add .AsEnumerable() It works as shown below

```
public UserProfile LoadUserDetails(Int64 userId)
    {
        var userProfile = new UserProfile();

        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            userProfile = (from p in context.UserProfile.AsEnumerable()
                           where p.UserId == userId
                           select new UserProfile()
                           {
                               UserId = userId,
                               Firstname = p.Firstname,
                               Surname = p.Surname,
                               Username = p.Username,
                               CurrentlyOnline = p.CurrentlyOnline,
                               JoinedDate = p.JoinedDate,
                               UserLocation = p.UserLocation
                           }).FirstOrDefault();

            context.Dispose();
        }
        return userProfile;
    }
```

Now as mentioned above I fixed the error with the following code, purely because every solution I read geared more towards this approach, I load the user in to a temp class, create a new instance of the UserProfile() and populate the relevant variables from the temp class.

```
public UserProfile LoadUserDetails(Int64 userId)
    {
        var userProfile = new UserProfile();

        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var t = (from p in context.UserProfile
                     where p.UserId == userId
                     select new
                     {
                         UserId = userId,
                         Firstname = p.Firstname,
                         Surname = p.Surname,
                         Username = p.Username,
                         CurrentlyOnline = p.CurrentlyOnline,
                         JoinedDate = p.JoinedDate,
                         UserLocation = p.UserLocation
                     }).FirstOrDefault();

            userProfile = new UserProfile
            {
                UserId = userId,
                Firstname = t.Firstname,
                Surname = t.Surname,
                Username = t.Username,
                CurrentlyOnline = t.CurrentlyOnline,
                UserLocation = t.UserLocation,
                JoinedDate = t.JoinedDate
            };

            context.Dispose();
        }
        return userProfile;
    }
```

So the question I appose to you is what one is the best approach code example 2 or 3? taking in to consideration the performance.

I'm learning Entity framework 6 so ideally I want to use it correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track using `.AsEnumerable()`. I would do it like this:

```
public UserProfile LoadUserDetails(int userId) {
    using (var context = new Context()) {
        userProfile = context.UserProfile
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
    }
}
```

You can first do `.Where(...)` and then `.FirstOrDefault()` but you can just add the where-criteria in the call to `.FirstOrDefault(...)`.

If you do not want to select all the columns of the `UserProfile` class, then you should create a separate data holder class for that purpose. But you cannot user that class in your linq queries. Your query would then become something like:

```
public SmallUserProfile LoadUserDetails(int userId) {
    using (var context = new Context()) {
        userProfile = context.UserProfile
            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
            .Select(x => new SmallUserProfile {
                UserId = x.userId,
                // etc...
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new SmallUserProfile {
                UserId = x.userId,
                // etc...
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

But this second version is basically identical to one of your versions.

Comment: Ok cool, I think I'll extend that to only return the 7 fields I need as I don't really need all 15 columns in the UserProfile and from what I have been taught is only select the columns you need to help with performance.

Comment: As a general guideline, true, only select what you need. But if you select a single row from your table, the performance you gain if fairly small I think. On the other hand, if you call the method with the query many millions of times...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to iron out due to the fact I could have 5000+ users hitting this application so ideally I'm treading carefully and trying to implement a suitable approach to this because the last thing I would want is for the application to come to a grinding halt.

Comment: Personally I would not optimize this by selecting only some columns. Try to fix performance where it is needed. You cannot optimize the performance beforehand. "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 0):

I think performance is not the issue but that code is very verbose.  I would consider using the [Find function on DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) to do the following.  This code makes the assumption that context.UserProfile is of Type DbSet if this is not the case it needs to be able to be converted to DbSet and that the UserId property on UserProfile is the Entity's key.

```
public UserProfile LoadUserDetails(Int64 userId)
{
    // Assuming context.UserProfile is / can be converted to DbSet<UserProfile>
    // and the userId is the Key to the Entity

    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        return context.UserProfile.Find(userId);
    }
}
```

This will do roughly what your code is doing.  You might want to do some checking / error handling if nothing matches the primary key.

Comment: so in your personal opinion would you say the code example you have given would be better i.e from a performance point of view? I'll add some error catching around that though

Comment: also from my personal experience, I don't really want to select everything from the UserProfile table as I only need the 7 columns currently in question, and the UserProfile table has about 15 coloumns @AlexC

Comment: Profile the cost of those 7 vs 15 columns and see if there is any measurable difference, I would be interested to see the results.  Then weigh that against the cost of maintenance on the additional code you write.  Also consider the cost of subtle bugs that might occur when code using UserProfile object returned by LoadUserDetails accesses properties that you have decided to populate with default values.